# Variable initializer redundant

Tags: java

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, but here is a snippet of my code. I get the warning for my `line` variable

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

String line = "" ;
while(( line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ){
    stringBuffer.append(line);
}
```

Comment: Why not use newer APIs? `new String(Files.readAllBytes(...), UTF-8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning simply means that the empty string with which the `line` variable is initialized is useless.

Before `line` is read, it is being assigned in the loop declaration:

```
line = bufferedReader.readLine()
```

So assigning `line = ""` is redundant. You can leave it uninitialized:

```
String line;
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Append to @ernest_k answer, assigning `line = ""` is redundant only if you reassign `line` with another value and you don't use `line` in return statement or set statement (set value need at least null value).